# Unable use Windows built-in solution to add a driver for an HP Deskjet 6127

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

```
UPDATED-STATEMENT: 2019@WEEK17 post created
UPDATED-STATEMENT: 20190425@081155@THU Due to no more support from HP, the HP Deskjet 6127 may only be used if drivers are from a Windows XP print server when installing onto a pc using Windows 7 or Windows 10.
```

I am on Windows 10 (win10_1803.17134.706) and have an HP Deskjet 6127 and the built in solution for adding a printer is not working at all. I can't find drivers for my printer so I skip ahead and look for hp-deskjet-990c drivers instead. I can’t install this driver I just downloaded because they’re for Windows XP giving me an error during installation.

I can’t use Windows add-a-printer because both 6127/990c isn’t listed even after updating the list which took a long time. I was then only left with downloading drivers for 990c, but they're incompatible with Windows 10 even after changing compatibility mode.

Some notes:

- Sometimes when a driver isn't found, you can substitute it with a [compatible alternative](https://www.driverscape.com/download/hp-deskjet-990c) as [mentioned here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01796821).
- Product & Driver

  - HP Deskjet 6127: Exclusive to Windows add-a-printer if not found use compatible alternative
  - [HP Deskjet 990c](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-990c-printer-series/25303): [Driver here](https://www.driverscape.com/download/hp-deskjet-990c).

Comment: Did you check HP's website for a driver?

Comment: I wasn't able to find the support page for it. I know it exists becuase I browsed through it yesterday and it simply puts that users have to use the Add-a-printer method which is Windows built-in way of doing it. Problem is, it's not listed same with the compatible alternative being hp-deskjet-990c even after updating the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're PC is Windows 7 to Windows 10 and still can't find drivers automatically via built in solution by `add a printer`, then install the [alternative drivers being HP Deskjet 990c on a PC using Windows XP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-990c-printer-series/25303) and set it as a print server by *allowing to share it.* Then on a PC that may be Windows 7/10 install printer from the winxp print server.

Otherwise **you can get lucky** and use `add a printer` and the compatible driver being HP Deskjet 990c is already there ready for you to install. This even may only happen if you update windows and keep files using the "Upgrade Product" method of Windows 7 to 10. So, a fresh install of Windows 7/10 **will NOT have any way to get these drivers.**

It's important to note that HP Deskjet 6127 doesn't have any physical drivers for Windows 7/10, because it only is for Windows XP. Only support for it for win7/10 is through the built in solution and suddenly it no longer is part of Windows Update. Now, that's not reliable.